# JS Promise.all to wait for asyncronous operations inside loop

Tags: javascript, promise

I am doing 2 DB calls inside the loop below in order to get the item's `statsID` and `countryCode`. I am logging both of them inside the loop and the result is just fine. However, the stored result (the variable named `withAdditionalData`) never gets consoled after the `Promise.all()` . It somewhere gets stuck and I do not know why. Thanks for any hint!

```
const body = d.data
const countriesWithNoCode = []
const withAdditionalData = await Promise.all(body.map(async (item) => {
    //get stats_id
    const statsM = new statsModel()
    const statsID = await statsM.getStatsId(item.BeverageTypes.trim())
    console.log(statsID) // is fine

    //check if country can be found by 2-digit code
    const countryCode = await statsM.getCountryCode(item.Country.toString().trim());

    if(!countryCode){
        countriesWithNoCode.push(item.Country.toString().trim())
    }
    console.log(countryCode) // is fine
    return {item, item.countryCode: countryCode, item.statsId: statsID}
}))

//it never consoles the following / it never gets there
console.log('withAdditionalData') 
console.log(withAdditionalData)
```

Comment: `return {item, item.countryCode: countryCode, item.statsId: statsID}` did you mean `return {item, countryCode: item.countryCode, statsID: item.statsId}`.

Comment: Or `return { ...item, countryCode, statsID }`?

Comment: if I use spread operator { ...item, countryCode, statsID }, it tells me "Syntax error, unexpected token" and without spread {item, countryCode: item.countryCode, statsID: item.statsId} it still never consoles "withAdditionalData" it just gets stuck ...

Comment: Try logging `body.length` and make sure that really all of your iterations return a promise that's actually resolved.

Comment: yes one single item did not return a promise. Inside my Model, I was returning the DB-result only when result had a length and there was one item not found in DB resulting in no Primise being returned ... thanks a lot!